# Subtracting dates formats in bash

Tags: bash, scripts, time, date, syntax

I am trying to create a countdown - most likely the hard way. I have it setup like this:

```
#! /bin/bash 

#When to execute command 
execute=$(date +"%T" -d "22:30:00")

#Current time
time=$(date +"%T")

#Subtract one from the other.... the below is line 11
math=$(("$execute"-"$time"))

#Repeat until time is 22:30:00
until [ "$math" == "00:00:00" ]; do  

echo "Countdown is stopping in $math"
sleep 1
clear 
done
```

**The problem is.... It isn’t working.** Here’s the output in the terminal:

```
   /path/to/file/test.sh: line 11: 22:30:00-16:39:22: syntax error in expression (error token is “:30:00-16:39:22”) 
    Countdown is stopping in
```

Firstly, the error message, what’s wrong?

Secondly, the “Countdown is stopping in” message should have the hours, minutes, and seconds that the countdown will stop in. Why doesn’t it? Keep in mind I am not a professional.

Comment: arithmetic expansion does not handle dates ... best is to convert the dates to epoch.

Comment: If you need to execute a job at a certain time, consider using `cron` instead.

Comment: @MarcVanhoomissen, cron can't do what I want it to. Firstly, it never executes the commands that are scheduled (it doesn't work for me). Secondly, I have a script that executes in Startup Applications. This script points to any programs or other scripts that I want to start after starting up the computer. The script that contains the countdown is executed by the startup script. The countdown script contains a bunch of commands that get executed then it schedules a shutdown and counts down to the shutdown in a new terminal window....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the statement

```
math=$(("$execute"-"$time"))
```

Because `execute` and `time` contain values in the format `%H:%M:%S`. But bash's [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html) can't evaluate time formats.

Instead of `%H:%M:%S` format, you can convert times into seconds, do the arithmetic and then print in the desired format.

Something like

```
#!/bin/bash

#When to execute command
execute=$(date +"%s" -d "22:30:00")

time=$(date +"%s")
math=$((execute-time))

if [[ $math -le 0 ]]; then
    echo "Target time is past already."
    exit 0
fi

#Repeat until time is 22:30:00
while [[ $math -gt 0 ]]; do
    printf "Countdown is stopping in %02d:%02d:%02d" $((math/3600)) $(((math/60)%60)) $((math%60))
    sleep 1
    clear

    # Reset count down using current time;
    # An alternative is to decrease 'math' value but that
    # may be less precise as it doesn't take the loop execution time into account
    time=$(date +"%s")
    math=$((execute-time))
done
```

Comment: Your script worked perfectly. After the initial comment to my question, I started editing my script to make the adjustments. It was almost exactly like yours when I finished, but I ended up using your script because it looked more organized. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Actually, after rebooting, your script did not work. I tried to run the script, no output was displayed.

Comment: @CJ-- It's due to the while/until mixup I had. I think it should work now.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Linux, so does ```lt``` mean "less than?" If so,  ```while [[ $math -lt $execute ]]; do ...``` is incorrect. ```$math``` will always be less than ```$execute```. When the time hits 22:30, ```$math``` will equal 0, but ```$execute``` will equal 22:30 (but in the format of seconds). I do like the ```if [[ $math -le 0 ]]; then
    echo "Target time is past already."
    exit 0``` that you added in though.

Comment: @CJ-- Yes, `lt` is for "less than"; `le` is for "less than or equal"; `gt` is for "greater than". More at: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html I tweaked the condition to fix that. Does it work for now?

Comment: I have been using the script that I added as a second answer to this question. Your script looks like it would work.  Mine works well, and is basically the same thing as your script. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, @P.P for the answer. Your method worked at first, but stopped working after a reboot.... Also, it didn't stop the cycle - meaning it went into negative numbers and never executed commands afterwards. This is what I ended up doing:

```
#! /bin/bash

#When to execute command
execute=$(date +"%s" -d "22:30:00")

time=$(date +"%s")
math=$((execute-time))

#Repeat until time is 22:30:00
until [ "$time" == "$execute" ]; do
    printf "The server will stop in %02d:%02d:%02d" $((math/3600)) $(((math/60)%60)) $((math%60))
    sleep 1
    clear

    # Reset count down using current time;
    # An alternative is to decrease 'math' value but that
    # may be less precise as it doesn't take the loop execution into account
    time=$(date +"%s")
    math=$((execute-time))

if [ "$time" == "$execute" ]; then

break
fi 

done 

echo "Cycle has ended"
```

Comment: Since `"$time" == "22:30:00"` can never be true when using the `+%s` format, you may as well use an infinite loop like `while : ; do`

Comment: @steeldriver, that is true. I’ll edit that into my script. Thanks for the suggestion. I replaced the ```“22:30:00”``` in ```”$time” == “22:30:00”``` ```“$execute“```